# Создание WCF клиента на готовый SOAP web сервер

Tags: c#, wcf

Доброго времени суток.
Появилась задача опрашивать web сервер с клиента на котором планируется написать WCF клиентскую часть. 
Информации про сервер очень мало (не знаю платформу хоста) знаю только формат SOAP сообщений.

Цитата из тех задания выглядит вот так:

> Для  нормативного расписания  интерфейс WEB сервера GetScheduleNormative4Place
>   запрос:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding=" utf-8" ?>
  <root>
    <Authentication User=’ddd’ Password=’samba’/>
    <Place ESR=’34567’/>
  </root >
```

> ответ:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding=" utf-8" ?>
<root>
<Place ESR=’34567’ Data=’2015.09.21’/>
  <Train TrainNumber=’6022’ Name=’Москва-Ожерелье’ ESRDeparture=’34567’ ESRArrival=’34560’ TimeDeparture=’2015.09.21 11:11:00’ TimeArrival=’’ DaysTrainType=’ОН’ DaysTrain= ‘2015.09.15;2015.09.17;2015.09.22’ >
  </Train>
</root >
```

То есть в запросе к конечной точке указываю авторизационные данные и какой-то Id номер и если они верные, то сервер выкидывает ответ.

Мне нужно создать клиента на WCF под платформу .NET 4.5.
Один раз делал распределенное приложение и там я классически создавал контракт который применял и к клиентской части и к серверной. Здесь сервер уже сделан и я так понимаю что одна из конечных точек должна быть mex (метаданные). И в VS можно даже через кодогенерацию создать проект WCF клиента который по метаданным, полученным от сервера, содласт клиента? вроде видел такие примеры.
Какие есть способы создать клиента в ручную? И если отключен mex?

Заранее всем спасибо!

Comment: Давно этого не делал, но вроде как у сервиса должна быть страница с описанием протокола (Примерно так https://host/service(.asmx)?wsdl),  ее можно сгрузить и скормить утилите wsdl.exe, она генерирует прокси-классы, добавить из в проект и использовать... П.с.wsdl.exe ставится вместе со студией

Comment: вроде в 2015 студии. это делается как добавление ссылки на сборки в проект и там указывается адресс запушенного сервиса. но на сервисе должна быть одна из конечных точек mex. и генерируется обычный код, потом можно создать прокси объект и вызвать метод на сервере.

Comment: а можно ли хардкорно имея только формат запроса и ответа создать подходящий контракт (интерфейс) для общения?

Comment: объект находится в другом городе и я хочу по максимум подготовится к неожидоностям))

Comment: Для этого от сервера нужно получить контракт, руками описывать муторно... Когда писал интеграции с банками, они присылали именно WSDL и по нему я генерировал прокси типы... Руками никогда не описывал, простите...

Comment: А по поводу того, что в студии кормишь ссылку, а он клиента создает, это тоже верно, делается тоже самое, что я описал выше, только в интерфейсе студии, а не в командной строке. Для того что бы на студии сгенерить прокси объект нужно по проекту ткнуть ПКМ и выбрать Add->Service Reference...

Comment: Add->Service Reference. Ага это я и имел в виду. Просто это РЖД (вокзал в Москве) и серверу там лет 10. Попытаюсь почитать про  создание SOAP объектов в C# (может как XML объекты...) и хардкорное общение через http socket. Но надеятся буду на лучтшее).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47039/discussion-between-kimaman2-and-aldmi).